# how do I get the boundaries of a googlemaps api map when using gmaps.js

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm using the google maps api gmaps.jd  with https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/
I can't access the bounds of the map via getBounds() it always returns undefined.

```
 function drawMap(lat,lng, target, zoom){
   var map = new GMaps({
    div: target,
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng,
    zoom: zoom,
   scrollwheel: false,

});
return map;
}
map =  drawMap(51.5073346,-0.1276831, '#homeMap', 9);
console.log(map.getBounds()); //always undefined
```

How can I accecess the maps boundaries when using gmpaps.js and googlemaps api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are trying to get the bounds too soon. The map is created asynchronously, so your code to get the bounds executes before the map has been created.

You can register an event handler to wait until the map is created before you get the bounds:

```
map = drawMap(51.5073346,-0.1276831, '#homeMap', 9);
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map.map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    console.log(map.getBounds());
});
```

Note: Since this uses `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce()` to register the event handler, it must be passed the native `google.maps.Map` object, which is obtained by calling `map.map`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joz8pu4c/)

Comment: thank you I had tried this with

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map.map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    console.log(map.getBounds());
});

which of course never fired